# How to set image priority when linking via Facebook for example?

Tags: facebook

You know if you were to post you website into a status or comment on Facebook and it then takes your meta headers and arranges your site title, description etc neatly into a link.

It also uses one of your images randomly on your website as a thumbnail preview. You can of course change before you post the link but I remember reading there was a way to set the priority for your images to appear in this instance. At the minute it just takes the highest image in the code.

Is there a way to do this, can someone give me the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Facebook Sharer select Images?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

Comment: Seems to be the same question, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about priority but you can set an image by adding an image source meta tag to the head of your document.

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://domain.top/yourimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it doesn't use that image as the thumbnail!

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnails of these images from meta tags are cached on Facebook. The priority is following the rule: higher res images will come first. The idea is from:

[How to set priority order to Open Graph images for links that are inserted in comments. (Not sharing or wall posts.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365156/how-to-set-priority-order-to-open-graph-images-for-links-that-are-inserted-in-co/12726245#12726245)

Hope it will help.